# Bootcamp Disk Partition Error (APFS error code 49187)

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, error

First of all, I downloaded the iso file to bootcamp and opened the Bootcamp assistant. After the support program was downloaded, the disk went to the partitioning stage but started giving an error.

Error: Disk Partition error (continued Run First Aid)

I tried a few more times, but it didn't work. I also deleted the SSD device through the recovery mode and reinstalled it. Restarting Bootcamp I got the Disk Partition error again. I tried to partition the test disk myself, but got an error again. (error code 49187)

-NVRAM and SMB reset
-Disc First aid
-Root user
-New Admin User
-A few terminal commands
-Re-download the iso file

For about a week, nothing worked for me.

Comment: Which version of Windows? What model/year Mac? If this the original internal drive? Is macOS installed and running on this drive?

Comment: Please clarify what doubts you have and what do you need help with specifically?

Comment: This is the best answer. Solved errors on my Mac !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much effort, I found the solution.

1. I boot the device in recovery mode.
2. Open terminal and type diskutil. (To get the disc numbers from the list)
3. diskutil verifyVolume containerdisknumber 
   disk util verifyVolume MacintoshHDdiskNumber
4. diskutil repairVolume containerdisknumber 
   diskutil repairVolume MacintoshHDdiskNumber

and I exited the terminal and restarted the computer. When I restarted the bootcamp everything went fine and completed successfully. I hope it helps anyone who has the same problem.